# Straight Skeleton from concave polygon in CGAL

Tags: python, cgal

I have an image from which I extract contours and turn these into polygons, using the code below *see image below:*

[image: Base]

[image: Polygons]

```py
import os
from scipy import ndimage
from skimage import io, measure, img_as_bool, img_as_ubyte, filters
import skgeom as sg
from skgeom.draw import draw
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Read in the image:
filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'traces.png')
traces = img_as_ubyte(io.imread(filename))

#Find contours in of the traces:
Alpha = traces[:,:,3]
bool = img_as_bool(Alpha)
filled = ndimage.binary_fill_holes(bool)
gaussian = filters.gaussian(filled)
countours = measure.find_contours(gaussian, 0.9)

#Display the image and plot all contours found as polygons:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(32,16))

skels = []
for countour in countours:
    approximated_countour = measure.approximate_polygon(countour, 10)
    poly = sg.Polygon(approximated_countour)
    draw(poly)
    print(poly.is_simple())
    #skels.append(sg.skeleton.create_interior_straight_skeleton(poly)) #Causes error!

ax.axis('off')
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```

The output in the console:

```py
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
```

I'm using a python wrapper for CGAL called scikit-geometry.

CGAL reports all the polygons as being not-simple, however as far as I'm aware they should be simple. They do not intersect themselves anywhere and do not have any duplicate points.

Due to CGAL being convinced the polygons are not-simple the function `create_interior_straight_skeleton` throws an error and halts.

The error:

```
RuntimeError: CGAL ERROR: precondition violation!
Expr: aOutContour.is_simple() || !"The input polygon is not simple."
File: D:\bld\scikit-geometry_1602638892768\_h_env\Library\include\CGAL/create_straight_skeleton_2.h
Line: 133
```

So, am I mistaken and are the polygons indeed not-simple. If so, how could I still skeletonize? Or Is the fault else where and am I doing something else wrong?

### **EDIT**

As requested the polygon files:  [Polygon Files](https://gist.github.com/Walthzer/7eaf548ca5a0ca04e5780bcd74b17dc9)

Code used to generate files:

```py
import os
from scipy import ndimage
from skimage import io, measure, img_as_bool, img_as_ubyte, filters
import skgeom as sg

#Read in the image:
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
filename = os.path.join(directory, 'traces.png')
traces = img_as_ubyte(io.imread(filename))

#Find contours in of the traces:
Alpha = traces[:,:,3]
bool = img_as_bool(Alpha)
filled = ndimage.binary_fill_holes(bool)
gaussian = filters.gaussian(filled)
countours = measure.find_contours(gaussian, 0.9)

#Save the polygons to a text file:
for index, countour in enumerate(countours):
    approximated_countour = measure.approximate_polygon(countour, 10)
    poly = sg.Polygon(approximated_countour)

    file = open(os.path.join(directory, "polygons\poly_{}.txt".format(index)), "w")
    for vertice in poly.vertices:
        file.write("{}, {}\n".format(vertice.x(), vertice.y()))
```

### **EDIT 2**

Thanks to @sloriot the not-being simple issue has been resolved. The first and last point were duplicate in every polygon.

Sadly the created skeletons are extremely deformed:
*Skeletons*
[image: skeleton]
*Skeletons zoomed in*
[image: Skeleton_zoomed_in]

Code used:

```py
import os
from scipy import ndimage
from skimage import io, measure, img_as_bool, img_as_ubyte, filters
import skgeom as sg
from skgeom.draw import draw
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Read in the image:
filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'traces.png')
traces = img_as_ubyte(io.imread(filename))

#Find contours in of the traces:
Alpha = traces[:,:,3]
bool = img_as_bool(Alpha)
filled = ndimage.binary_fill_holes(bool)
gaussian = filters.gaussian(filled)
countours = measure.find_contours(gaussian, 0.9)

def draw_skeleton(polygon, skeleton, show_time=False):
    draw(polygon)

    for h in skeleton.halfedges:
        if h.is_bisector:
            p1 = h.vertex.point
            p2 = h.opposite.vertex.point
            plt.plot([p1.x(), p2.x()], [p1.y(), p2.y()], 'r-', lw=2)

    if show_time:
        for v in skeleton.vertices:
            plt.gcf().gca().add_artist(plt.Circle(
                (v.point.x(), v.point.y()),
                v.time, color='blue', fill=False))

#Display the image and plot all contours found as polygons:

for countour in countours:
    approximated_countour = measure.approximate_polygon(countour, 10)

    if ((approximated_countour[0] == approximated_countour[-1]).all()):
        approximated_countour = approximated_countour[:-1]

    poly = sg.Polygon(approximated_countour)
    print(poly.is_simple())
    skel = sg.skeleton.create_interior_straight_skeleton(poly)

    draw_skeleton(poly, skel, True)

plt.show()
```

The code and the python library don't seem to be the issue as it works fine [here](https://scikit-geometry.github.io/scikit-geometry/skeleton.html) and that code also works fine when I tried it. Again, my polygons are the issue I fear. Note that it is also deformed if I limit the draw_skeleton() to just one polygon.

### **Final Edit**

The straight skeleton failed because I was creating the polygon with vertices in clockwise order. Reversing the order of points before creating the polygon has fixed this final issue.

Comment: Without any code nor data it is hard to tell you what's wrong. Maybe it is just a duplicated point in the input polygon?

Comment: @sloriot Added the code. Checked the polygons themselves, can't find any duplicate points.

Comment: If you give me the polygon files I can have a look but if the function says they are not simple, they are probably not simple. I'm a CGAL developer not a scipy developer so maybe there is an issue with the wrappers.

Comment: @sloriot hadn't thought about the wrapper being bust. I'll add a polygon file to the question asap. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: @sloriot I've added the polygon files.

Comment: The first and last points are identical. Try removing one of them.

Comment: @Sloriot Thanks for the help man! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When trying to use create_interior_straight_skeleton() make sure you polygon:**

- *Is simple -> No intersecting segments or duplicated points*
- *Has its vertices defined in counter-clockwise order.*

If the polygon is not simple, you'll be treated by an error stating such.

If the vertices are not in counter-clockwise order, your straight skeleton will look like a demon spawn and be incorrect.

*Thanks to @Sloriot for the help!*